# How to add id's to list <li> tags in HTML using Image Picker Dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Imagepicker.js](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/)

```
container.append(jQuery("<li id='some_id'>" + (option_group.attr("label")) + "</li>"));
```

I have tried adding id in the li, but it is not being added. Can someone suggest me the way to add id to the li.

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes correctly then

```
container.append("<li id='"+some_id+"'>" + (option_group.attr("label")) + "</li>");
```

Comment: Its not working, i tried it. Please refer imagepicker.js.

Comment: what is some_id..It should be your dynamic value

Comment: i kept the above code inside the for loop, and the replaced some id with loop's variablee, in the same way as you suggested.

Comment: can you check now.I think in append you only need to pass html.